# AngularJS excerpt function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have my HTML string stored in my DB (the content of my new post).

I know that to print this html in my view I can use this

```
<div ng-bind-html="post.content"></div>
```

And this is perfectly fine, but let's say I want to print only first 20 characers of parsed string.

Is there a way how I could store returned value of "ng-bind-html" and the just use filter on it?

Is there any better way how to create excerpt functionality in angular?

Comment: You can create a custom filter: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter

Answer (score 1):

You could have a custom filter:

```
app.filter('ellipsis', function () {
    return function (text, length) {
        if (text.length > length) {
            return text.substr(0, length) + '...';
        }
        return text;
    }
});
```

which you would use like this:

```
<div ng-bind-html="post.content | ellipsis:20"></div>
```

and here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FfT6s/348/

Comment: That doesn't exactly work. It would count the html characters. He wants to count only the text.

Comment: Then this is probably something you want to so on the server and return this information as a property to your view model.

Answer (score 0):

I just create some filters with npm modules.

[striptags](https://www.npmjs.com/package/striptags)
[ellipsize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ellipsize)

```
// stripTagsFilter.js
var striptags = require('striptags');

module.exports = function() {
  return function(input) {
    if (!input || !input.length) { return input; }
    return striptags.apply(null, arguments);
  }
};

// ellipsisFilter.js
var ellipsize = require('ellipsize');

module.exports = function() {
  return ellipsize;
};

// wherever you do this stuff
.filter('ellipsis', require('./ellipsisFilter.js'))
.filter('stripTags', require('./stripTagsFilter.js'))
```

```
<!-- strip the tags, limit to 20 characters -->
<p>{{post.content | stripTags | ellipsis:20}}</p>
```

Stripping the tags could squish sentences together in the remaining text, so you may want to add a filter to fix that as well. I suggest [space-sentences](https://www.npmjs.com/package/space-sentences).

```
<p>{{post.content | stripTags | spaceSentences | ellipsis:20}}</p>
```